# SQLiteConstraintException Best Practices for Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a pretty broad question and mainly want some advice and best practices for this Sqlite Exception and how to handle it. I am catching it no problem, just needing help with handling it. In my app, I have only one field for my database that is labeled unique for this reason, as I do not want this one particular value to be duplicated in the database. I am using the method `insertWithOnConflict()` but am wondering what is the best constant to set for the `conflictAlgorithm` parameter. I have read up on all of them that are available from the SQLiteDatabase|Android reference page and am still not sure which would be my best bet. I would ideally prefer to accomplish this:

Prompt the user immediately with either an `AlertDialogueBuilder` or `Toast` message that the value they have entered, is already contained in the database and they need to alter this current value before continuing. Since this unique field is one of the first one's out of all 15 of them, I would even be fine with writing and committing the current transaction with all the other data collected for the other remaining fields and just labeling that unique field with a message indicating a default "Needs Unique" value or something but this would be last resort. At this point, when the exception is caught, my app does not crash, it just does not commit the write, and returns to the previous calling `Activity`, which is a `listView` of all previously collected assets in the database. Would it be wise to just go ahead and relaunch the `Activity` where the data collection takes place, prompting them about the duplicate key at that time? Or stop the transaction from attempting to be committed and not written before the app is sent back to the calling `Activity`? I just can't seem to do anything with the exception once it happens. Any advice or tips would be greatly appreciated. Whatever are the best practices for working with data and databases I would like to know and learn for the future. Thank you all.

Comment: Constraints are designed to catch programming errors; you cannot easily determine *which* constraint was violated from the exception. And requiring the user to enter a unique value is bad UI; why can't the app generate a new value automatically? Couldn't entering an existing value result in the existing record being shown?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and information. I had not thought of your suggestion about showing the existing value if it is entered and will look at using that. Thanks